# Using contextlib in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to use `contextlib` with Python... But it returns me error... The code is

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import contextlib
class Mgr():
     def __enter__(self): 
         return self
     def __exit__(self, ext, exv, trb):
         if ext is not None: print "no not possible"
            print "OK I caught you"
            return True
     @contextlib.contextmanager
     def honey(self):
         print 'guli'

with contextmanager() as d:
     print d
```

When I run this code it haves me error like

```
TypeError: contextmanager() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

The code just works fine without `contextlib`. but I need to make it work with `contextlib`..

How can I invoke the `honey` function with `contextmanager`?..

Comment: `contextlib.contextmanager` is for turning a generator with a single `yield` into a context manager (A class with `__enter__` and `__exit__`)

Comment: @AnthonySottile so isnt it able to use it with functions inside classes ??

Comment: It is.  Here's an example: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/VFLhUrWBaQ0Fc2cvRfdJ/

Comment: yeah it works but it give me error like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'`..how can i solve it

Comment: @AnthonySottile why am i getting like that

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, note that syntax of the code you posted is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you misunderstood whole concept. There are two options of creating context maganer. First is 'traditional' way - creating class with magic `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

Other option is to use `contextmanager` decorator from `contextlib`. It decorates a **function**, and it's functionality is limited comparing to whole class.

Consider following:

```
import contextlib

class SampleContentManagerAsClass():
     def __enter__(self):
         print "Class Pre-Action"
         return self
     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
         if exc_type is not None:
             print "Exception raised."
         print "Class Post-Action"


@contextlib.contextmanager
def SampleContentManagerAsFunction():
    print "Function Pre-action"
    yield
    print "Function Post-action"

with SampleContentManagerAsClass() as cm:
     print cm

with SampleContetManagerAsFunction() as cm:
     print cm
```

Output:

```
Class Pre-Action
<__main__.SampleContentManagerAsClass instance at 0x7f1508552f80>
Class Post-Action
Function Pre-action
None
Function Post-action
```

Main differences:

- Class has easy way to get informations about raised exception. As far as I know, there is no such way for simplified decorated function.
- There is no "context-manager" object for decorated function (`as x` gives `None` for `x` - there is no much sense for using  `as`). It's expected behaviour as you cannot send message to function.

Comment: two correction: for the decorated function, if an exception is raised, it will appear to be raised from the `yield`. `as` also makes sense for the decorated version and will have whatever value that was `yield`d (plain `yield` is shorthand for `yield None` (in the same way that `return` is `return None`))

Comment: @AnthonySottile thanks, learning something every day. Yielding value is reasonable, but for exception part - you'll have to write explicit try/except statement with yield inside - right? If you care about raised exception I feel using a class is a much cleaner way...

Comment: @AnthonySottile so Lukasz states context manager for classes and function what about making the context manager of functions inside the class ??..is it possible

Comment: @AvinashBabu I'm not sure - I never seen it and honestly I cannot think of any suitable example. Is it an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @ŁukaszR. correct, you'll need `try: except:` or `try: finally:`.

Comment: @AvinashBabu: sure, I've given an example in the comments on the question: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/VFLhUrWBaQ0Fc2cvRfdJ/